# Postgres 9.6 Gather node finishing after aggregate when parallel workers are present

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I tried running "Explain Analyze" a select statement with parallel workers.

The query plan that it returns have Gather node taking more time than its parent, the Aggregate node.

Can anyone help me understand why this happens?

[image: Query plan snapshot for better understanding the issue]

Comment: It is probably a bug.  Can you reproduce it on something more recent?

Comment: No, could not produce for Postgres 10+